# Private method `gets' called for (NoMethodError) Ruby

Tags: ruby, error-handling, nomethoderror

Getting the error

```
 "private method `gets' called for `ot,Room 203,Healthcare Info Session,2014,6,17,14,0\n":String (NoMethodError)"
```

and not sure where my code is wrong.

Also the first line in `appointments.txt`:

```
ot,Room 203,Healthcare Info Session,2014,6,17,14,0
```

Can someone please let me know what needs to be changed in my code:

```
appointments = [ ]
file_object = File.open("appointments.txt", "r")

while line = file_object.gets
  fields = line.gets.chomp.split(',')
  appointment_type = [0]

  if appointment_type == 'ot'
    location = fields[1]
    purpose = fields[2]
    year = fields[3].to_i
    month = fields[4].to_i
    day = fields[5].to_i
    hour = fields[6].to_i
    minute = fields[7].to_i
    appt1 = OneTimeAppointment.new("Dentist", "Cleaning", 4, 45, 5, 20, 2017)
    appointments.push(appt1)
  else 
    location = fields[1]
    purpose = fields[2]
    hour = fields[3].to_i
    minute = fields[4].to_i
    day = fields[5].to_i
    appt2 = MonthlyAppointment.new("Doctor", "Cold", 2, 30, 15)
    appointments.push(appt2)
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call `gets` on a string. You call `gets` on the file to retrieve the line, but then you go and call `gets` on that line for some reason. This is incorrect.

A fix looks like this:

```
File.readlines('appointments.txt') do |line|
  fields = line.chomp.split(',')

  # ...
end
```

If you're reading CSV data you may want to consider using the [CSV library](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) that comes with Ruby.

Comment: `new': invalid date (ArgumentError) shows up when I add that code to my file

Comment: How can I fix this error?

Comment: Getting the error

     "rb:37:in `new': invalid date (ArgumentError)"

Comment: @Julian That's another question, and probably one that's already been answered. I bet your date isn't in the expected format.